# Can't SSH to keep latest 5 folders and delete the older folders

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

Currently I am using `ls -1t | tail -n +6 | xargs rm -rf` and it works fine at the server itself. But when I try it through ssh using root in a bash script, it doesn't run/work.

This is the line I am using : `ssh -q -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oConnectTimeout=1 root@$host "sudo cd /path/to/folder && sudo ls -1t | tail -n +6 | xargs rm -rf"`

May I know what's the issue here?

Comment: This should better be asked over at SuperUser or Unix & Linux. Also http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/; you should add a more detailed description of what is not working, e. g. error messages.

Comment: Your `sudo` can neither profit from the `cd` nor apply to the `xargs`.  You're lucky in the latter case!

Comment: Hi Murphy. Will do next time. Mata's post has cleared up my issues and help me understand better. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 1):

`root@$host` suggests that you're already logged in as root, so using `sudo` is redundant here.

```
cd /path/to/folder && ls -1t | tail -n +6 | xargs rm -rf
```

should do the trick.

But this is only safe if you exactly know that `/path/to/folder` can not contain any files with possibly dangerous characters in their names. For example a file named `..\n` or similar would cause the whole directory to be deleted.

The reason your original example does not work is that `sudo` executes a program, not a series of shell commands. Also `cd` is not a program but a shell builtin, so it can't be executed through `sudo`, as this wouldn't really make sense, the directory change would be lost after `cd` returned. If that worked, then in your case the first statement (`sudo cd /path/to/folder`) would execute successfully, and then the second one (`sudo ls -1t | tail -n +6 | xargs rm -rf`) would execute in the current directory, but only the `ls` command as root, the rest as the current user.

To execute the whole command line through `sudo`

```
sudo sh -c "cd /path/to/folder && ls -1t | tail -n +6 | xargs rm -rf"
```

Or, if the current user has access rights for `/path/to/folder`, then actually only the last part needs to be executed as root:

```
cd /path/to/folder && ls -1t | tail -n +6 | sudo xargs rm -rf
```

Comment: Running `tail` as root is probably harmless, but you should generally try to minimize what you run as a privileged user. Without access to the permissions, we don't know if `cd` and `ls` can be executed as a regular user, but perhaps `cd /path/to/folder && ls -1t | tail -n +6 | sudo xargs rm -rf` would work. (http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs is still a problem.)

Comment: @tripleee Good points, I would usually recommend something like `find ... -print0 | xargs -null ...` or `find ... -delete ...` in similar situations, but "all except the newest 6 entries in that directory" isn't possible (I think) with find. I'll update my answer to better reflect the possible issues.